# There is a page on my website that doesn't show in the Pages section of WordPress

Tags: posts

I am able to access the page when I type the URL, but the page doesn't exist in the  WordPress pages section.

Comment: You could check whether it's under Posts, or Categories, or a custom post type or custom taxonomy. You may also want to try deactivating all of your plugins and switching to a default theme like 2020 to see if it's a theme or plugin that's adding the page. Once you find out what's adding it, you can dig deeper to find out how it's being added and then whether or not you can edit in the Editor or if you would have to add code to make changes.

Comment: (You may also want to double-check and make sure you are logging in as an Admin. If it's a custom post type or taxonomy, you might not have access to edit it without Admin rights.)

Comment: It's entirely possible you're viewing a post archive or something automated.  A bit more info would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in as an admin. Then go to the page. Edit the page (on the black bar at the top of the screen).

Then look at all aspects of the page (enable all Screen Options) and see if there is something unusual.

The suggestion of temporary disable plugins is a good idea - you can do that quickly with your host's File Manager or FTP by renaming the plugin directory; then look in Admin, Pages; then changing the renamed plugins folder back to normal.

You could also try copying all of the page's content (in Text view) to a new page to see if the new page will show up. And look in the error logs to see  if there is a hint there.